# How to style pandas dataframe using a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, pandas-styles

I have a pandas dataframe like:

[image]

I need to style it using a list of lists like:

```
[[3, 7, 4, 5],
[6, 17, 5, 10, 13, 16],
[7, 22, 6, 17, 19, 12],
[12, 26, 24, 25, 23, 18, 20],
[21, 20, 18, 27, 25]]
```

If R1 values are in first list color blue, if R2 values are in second list color blue and so on.
In other words color numbers of each column if value is in the correspondent list.

I have tried:

```
def posclass(val):

    color = 'black'

    for i in range(5):
    
        if (val in list[i]):

            color = 'blue'

    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(posclass,  subset=['R1','R2','R3','R4','R5'])
```

But this is not working properly applying each list to each column.

The desired result is a dataframe with colored numbers (those that matches in each column with each list).

[image]

Comment: [please change the image to text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) , also the styling I cannot relate  from your expected output according to our code, please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40).reshape(-1,4), columns=[f'R{i}' for i in range(1,5)])
```

Input df:

```
   R1  R2  R3  R4
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
5  20  21  22  23
6  24  25  26  27
7  28  29  30  31
8  32  33  34  35
9  36  37  38  39
```

and

```
list_l = [[3, 7, 4, 5],
[6, 17, 5, 10, 13, 16],
[7, 22, 6, 17, 19, 12],
[12, 26, 24, 25, 23, 18, 20],
[21, 20, 18, 27, 25]]
```

Then:

```
def f(x):
    colpos = df.columns.get_loc(x.name)
    return ['color: blue' if n in list_l[colpos] else '' for n in x]
df.style.apply(f)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution @Scott Boston, I am trying to understand the use of the `.name` method, can you give some lights on it?

Comment: @Pakin Sure in this case. I am using apply, which is passing each dataframe column into the custom function, f.  The column of a dataframe is a pd.Series with the name of the column header in the dataframe.  Therefore, I am getting the name of each column passed into the fuction and determining the position of the list to check.

Comment: `.name` isn't a method.  It is an attribute of a pd.Series.

Comment: thanks, I am having some problems if I try to apply the function f to a dataframe that has many other colums but only applying it to the R's columns without droping the other columns

Comment: You can always add a print in your custom function to see exactly what is getting passed.

Comment: Yes, I think I see what is happening.  If your list of list doesn't have an "row" for each column in your dataframe, then you're having some alignment issues.